# Question about the definition of the underlying set of a module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am confused with the definition of the underlying set of a module. For $\mathbf{Z}$-modules $\mathbf{Z_2}\times\mathbf{Z_2}$ and $\mathbf{Z_4}$, can I think they have the same underlying set because they both have four elements? And can you give an example of different modules with the same underlying set? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they have the same underlying set in the sense that the two underlying sets are isomorphic as sets.

However, they don't have the same underlying abelian group since the two groups are not isomorphic as groups.

Comment: Thank you, so when we say two modules have the same underlying set, it means the two sets are isomorphic as sets? And what's the definition of the isomorphism of sets? Does that mean they have the same cardinality?

Comment: @6666 yes, the isomorphisms of sets are just bijections.  But be careful: depending on the context, an author might literally mean set equality rather than bijection.